# Java: можно ли реализовать абстрактный метод конкретными методом, используя аргументы-потомки аргументов абстрактного метода

Tags: java, ооп

Ниже сигнатура абстрактного метода:

```
public abstract KnowledgeElementRealisation clone(KnowledgeElementUpdate knowledgeElementUpdate);
```

Я пытаюсь реализовать этот метод в прямом потомке следующим образом:

```
public KnowledgeElementRealisation clone(ArticleUpdate articleUpdate){
    return new Article( /* некоторый код */ );
}
```

Класс ArticleUpdate является прямым потомком KnowledgeElementUpdate. Естественно, для реализации абстрактного метода мне необходимо повторить дословно его сигнатуру и этот код не компилируется.

Мне нужно:

1. задать абстрактный метод clone, чтобы нельзя было наследоваться без его реализации;
2. аргумент абстрактного метода должен иметь родительский тип по отношению к тем типам, которые будут иметь аргументы реализаций данного метода;
3. аргументы реализующих методов должны быть наследниками аргумента абстрактного метода - цель в том, чтобы аргументы конкретизировали тот класс, на основе которого в данной реализации метода будет осуществляться клонирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic можно применить по-другому. Вместо generic классов - generic метод

```
public abstract <T extends KnowledgeElementUpdate> KnowledgeElementRealisation clone(T knowledgeElementUpdate);
```

Тогда можно вызвать метод таким образом

```
KnowledgeElementRealisation ker = obj.<ArticleUpdate>clone(articleUpdate);
```

Компилятор выполнит проверку того, что переменная `articleUpdate` заявлена как `ArticleUpdate`.
Какая в этом практическая польза в Вашей ситуации судить Вам.
Есть тут пара моментов, из-за которых можно усомниться в  правильности именно такого подхода. Но это по обстоятельствам, по ситуации.

Ну а внутри самого наследника что мешает выполнить проверку и приведение типа?

```
@Override
public <T extends KnowledgeElementUpdate> KnowledgeElementRealisation clone(T knowledgeElementUpdate) {
    ArticleUpdate articleUpdate = (ArticleUpdate)knowledgeElementUpdate;
    return new Article( /* некоторый код */ );
}
```

Comment: думал что доеду до работы и допишу про generic метод, не успел =)

Comment: Да, скорее всего придётся внутри наследников проверять. Не хотелось так, но придётся, раз других вариантов нет. Спасибо :-)

Answer (score 5):

Для этого начиная с java 1.5 добавили Дженкрики([Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)).

Это по сути возможность обобщенного программирования.

```
private interface Update {}
private interface Realisation {}

private class Article implements Realisation {}
private class ArticleUpdate implements Update {}

private abstract class A<U extends Update, R extends Realisation> {
    public abstract R clone(U update);
}

private class B extends A<ArticleUpdate, Article> {
   @Override
    public Article clone(ArticleUpdate articleUpdate){
        return new Article( /* некоторый код */ );
    }
}
```

---

И Вы ей активно пользуетесь, когда создаете например `Map<String, String>`, в треугольных скобках ни что иное как указание компилятору не использовать тип `Object`, а использовать тип `String` в сигнатурах методов, вложенных коллекций итд.

А если Вы заглянете в исходный код интерфейса `Map` вы увидите следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и парочка сырых типов, которые не явно унаследованы от `Object`

---

PS: Вот неплохой [туториал от oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) про дженерики.

Answer (score 3):

Если по порядку:

1) Если метод в потомке не реализован хотя бы один абстрактный метод предка проект даже не соберётся;

2 и 3) Создаёте некий базовый класс и указываете его в качестве типа аргумента.

Например:

```
protected abstract clone (MyBaseClass argumentValue);
```

В этом случае методу `clone` можно будет передать любого потомка `MyBaseClass`.

Comment: Да, хороший совет. Но мне нужно требовать более конкретный тип аргумента при реализации. Задача требует, чтобы при реализации метода аргумент был наследником, а не общим. Я могу это сделать страшненько, но хотелось бы красиво за счет абстрактного метода и возможности ожидать потомка класса аргумента абстрактного метода. То есть при реализации нужно ждать не ЛЮБОГО потомка, а именно КОНКРЕТНОГО потомка.

Comment: Тогда Вам придётся либо писать перегрузку для метода либо обратиться к дженерикам.